# Delete rows based on values in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to delete rows based on values . For example

```
df
ColA   ColB
A      1
B      2    
A      3
```

Expected output (Basically i know we can delete based on row number. But is there way to way to delete based on values ("A", 3)

```
df
ColA   ColB
A      1
B      2
```

Comment: check out the [`subset`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/subset) function `subset(df, !(ColA == "A" & ColB == 3))`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `which()` function (`?which`). You can then use this with a minus sign in conjunction with with indexing to subset based on a particular criteria.

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind("ColA"=c("A", "B", "A"), "ColB" = c(1, 2, 3)))

df <- df[-which(df[,2]==3),]

View(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset` from base R

```
> subset(df,!(ColA=="A"&ColB==3))
  ColA ColB
1    A    1
2    B    2
```

or a `data.table` solution

```
> setDT(df)[!.("A",3),on = .(ColA,ColB)]
   ColA ColB
1:    A    1
2:    B    2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(!(ColA == "A" & ColB == 3))
```